# state.getStore() or mapStateToProps - React.js / Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So I'm building my first Redux project to learn it. I just got it to output updated state in the middleware logger so that was great.

Now I am trying to have the component update based on the updated state.

Obviously I'm missing some fundamental concept here...I think I'm supposed to mapStateToProps but I just don't understand it.

Isn't there some simple global thing I can use?

How come when I console out store.getState().quote it works but doesn't update the component?

QUOTE COMPONENT

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import quoteReducer from './reducers/quoteReducer';

const logger = createLogger();
const store = createStore(
  quoteReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk, promise, logger)
);

class quote extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.responseType = "json";

        req.onload = function(){
            store.dispatch({type: "ADD_QUOTE", text: req.response.quote, movie: req.response.author});
        }.bind(this)

        req.open("GET", "http://localhost:3001/quote");
        req.send();
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div id="quote">
                <h1> "{store.getState().quote}" </h1>
                <h2> -{store.getState().author} </h2>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default connect()(quote);
```

REDUCER

```
const quoteReducer = (state = {quote: "", author: ""}, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_QUOTE':
            return {
                quote: action.text,
                author: action.movie
            }

        default:
            return state
    }

}

export default quoteReducer;
```

ACTION

```
export const addQuote = (text, movie) => {
    return {
        type: "ADD_QUOTE",
        text,
        movie
    }
}
```

APP.JS

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Quote from './quote';
import AnswerInput from './answerInput';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import './quote.css';
import './answerInput.css';
import './assets/styles/global.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Quote />
        <AnswerInput />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

INDEX.JS

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import quoteReducer from './reducers/quoteReducer.js';
import './index.css';

let store = createStore(quoteReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>        
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: you have to do mapStateToProps. If you do it global way then all components will rerender when there is change. So do it component wise itself

Comment: on the initial render `store.getState().author` is empty, and after the `dispatch` React doesn't gets notified that something is changed. So there is no re-render triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting some help from a contact and this is the code that worked!

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addQuote } from './actions';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { quote } = state;
  return quote; //This would be the job for selectors (from advanced redux tutorial)
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  addQuote(req) {
    const { quote, author } = req.response;
    dispatch(addQuote(quote, author)); // Use the action creator
  }
})

class Quote extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.responseType = "json";

        req.onload = function(){
          this.props.addQuote(req);
        }.bind(this)

        req.open("GET", "http://localhost:3001/quote");
        req.send();

        // the whole bit above is best replaced with a redux-fetch middleware
    }

    render(){
        const {quote, author} = this.props;

        return (
            <div id="quote">
                <h1> "{quote}" </h1>
                <h2> -{author} </h2>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

const ConnectedQuote = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Quote);

export default ConnectedQuote;
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @Konstantin Vitkovsky is *sort* of right, but not exactly.

There's a few problems with your original example:

First, your `quote` component should have a capitalized name, like `Quote`.  React and JSX use capitalization to know whether you're trying to render a component or an individual tag.  First letter uppercase means it's a component, first letter lowercase means it must be a tag.

Second, your component is currently accessing the store directly, and calling `store.getState()` in its `render` method.  This will work the first time, but because your component has no idea when the store updates, it will not trigger a re-render.  (Also, in React, ideally a `render()` method should *only* render things based on `this.props` and `this.state`.)

Third, you *are* calling the React-Redux `connect` method at the end of your file, but you're not actually *using* it in any way.

Finally, you definitely shouldn't refer to the store directly in the component.  You should render a `<Provider store={store}>` component at the top of your component tree, which will make the store accessible to any connected component inside of it.

As @Konstantin Vitkovsky said, your component will not know that the store has been updated unless your component subscribes to the store.  However, that is *exactly* what `connect` already does for you.  Every time the store updates, the wrapper component generated by `connect` will re-run the `mapStateToProps` function you gave it, and pass the data that you return into your "real" component.

So, for your example, your code should look roughly like this:

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {Provider, connect} from "react-redux";

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

// Normally the store definition and the component would be
// defined in different files
class Quote extends Component {
    render() {
        const {quote, author} = this.props;

        return (
            <div id="quote">
                <h1>{quote}</h1>
                <h2>{author}</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        quote : state.quote,
        author : state.author
    };
}

const ConnectedQuote = connect(mapStateToProps)(Quote);


ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}
        <Quote />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I'd encourage you to read through the [Redux docs](http://redux.js.org/) thoroughly - they contain a *lot* of good information.  Also, I keep a big list of links to high-quality tutorials and articles on React, Redux, and related topics, at https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links .  It's specifically intended to be a great starting point for anyone trying to learn the ecosystem.

Comment: You are missing a close bracket after your connect call.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I am a bit confused still. I have added my App.js & Index.js. I had my provider and root in Index.js. Which renders the App component and the quote component is inside the App component.

Comment: Okay, so you've got that part taken care of already.  In that case, you just need to actually use `connect` properly, per my example.  In your original code, your call to `connect` wasn't doing anything useful, because you weren't providing a `mapStateToProps` function to extract data from the store, and you were trying to reference the store directly.

Comment: Darn, yeah I dunno what's up then. I don't want to change the original post otherwise it won't make sense to readers but I did put in the changes on my local. I'll have to play around thanks for your help.

Comment: If you're still having issues, drop by the Reactiflux channels on Discord ( http://www.reactiflux.com ) and ask in #need-help .  Plenty of people around to help, and I'm usually on there in the evenings.